# How to insert special keys (like <return>, <m-r>) into macro registers with script?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, macro

I tried `let @q = '<return>'` and it obviously won't work

Answer (score 1):

`<return>` is not completely wrong. You just need to use double-quote and add backslash. For example:

```
:let @q = "ihello\<Return>vim\<Esc>"
```